# set width and height of a drawable object in runtime process in android

Tags: android

Hi I have a `drawable` object in which content is loaded at `runtime` process.I want to get its actual width and height so I used this code :

```
int x=drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int y=drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
```

Ans the result is x as 72 and y as 72.Now I want to set my `drawable` object width and height as 72.How can I do that.Is there any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourAwesomeDrawable);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
// Scale it to 100 x 100
Drawable newDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, true));
```

You could also try `setBounds()`, but I am not quite sure..

Comment: hii I have tried this it is working .My drawable contains any third party app icon(e.g. facebook).When I set drawable icon in imageview it looks perfectly on my device screen 4.5 inch screen.but when i test it in 5 inch screen or larger device it shrinks and looks small

Answer (score 0):

You use the setBounds method.  setBounds takes a rectangle you wish to draw it in.  Make sure the rectangle is 72 by 72.  This also sets its location at the same time, so you have to do it after you know where you wish to place it.